# Usage of Direct Database Call Without Caching Error

Tags: database, cache

I have a custom function that creates a dynamic copyright year range based on the year of the first and last posts in the database:

```
function jldc_copyright_dates() {
    global $wpdb;
    $copyright_dates = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT
            YEAR(min(post_date_gmt)) as firstdate,
            YEAR(max(post_date_gmt)) as lastdate
        FROM
            $wpdb->posts
    " );

    if ( $copyright_dates ) {
        $copyright_year = $copyright_dates[0]->firstdate;
        if ( $copyright_dates[0]->firstdate !== $copyright_dates[0]->lastyear ) {
            $copyright_year .= '&mdash;' . $copyright_dates[0]->lastdate;
        }
        echo esc_html( $copyright_year . '&nbsp;'; );
    }
}
```

I am using PHPCS with the WordPress VIP code standards and when I run it on this file I get a warning: `Usage of a direct database call is discouraged.`

In addition, I also get an error `Usage of a direct database call without caching is prohibited. Use wp_cache_get / wp_cache_set or wp_cache_delete.`

How would I go about testing to see if these values are cached and if not, cache them to make this error go away?

Comment: there is very little that can be said when you show only part of the code. Unlikely that the code displayed here causes the error

Comment: A lot of people will say that the copyright year is unnecessary, and others will point out that by moving the year forwards you're actually relinquishing copyright for the previous year. If this were a VIP review I'd suggest you remove it, or better yet just say "all rights reserved". Notice how this site simply states the license in the footer

Comment: @MarkKaplun it's the VIP coding standards in PHPCS throwing up an error, there's no actual PHP error here

Comment: @TomJNowell, Oh ok,but probably not from this specific snippet. I don't see anything that access the cache, or am I wrong and VIP does something unexpected on $wpdb queries?

Comment: @MarkKaplun The errors I posted are the word-for-word ones I am getting from PHPCS. The only other thing in functions.php are my styles/script enqueues and those passed PHPCS just fine.

The code itself works other than the firstdate being 0.

Comment: @belinus, the error have to originate from somewhere, and the function you are giving here doesn't look like a possible source. or at least you should specify the exact line which triggers it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun The VIP ruleset will flag all direct SQL queries as an issue, regardless of what the query does, which is intended behaviour, the OP was right, and that code should flag as a blocker when using the VIP ruleset or the VIP Scanner tool

Comment: @TomJNowell Yeah, I decided to pull it off the site footer and instead have it in each individual post. The actual date doesn't matter since it'll expire 75 years after I'm dead anyways :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Tom J Nowell:

> I'd suggest you remove it, or better yet just say "all rights reserved".

But in the quest for answers, here's a suggestion using an option field to cache the years:

```
/**
 * Get year range for posts.
 * 
 * @return str
 */
function wpse_226627_get_copyright() {
    if ( ! $years = get_option( 'copyright' ) ) {
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type'      => get_post_types([ 'public' => true ]),
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'orderby'        => 'post_date',

            /**
             * Don't waste memory we don't need
             */
            'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'cache_results'          => false,
        ];

        $newest = get_posts([ 'order' => 'DESC' ] + $args );
        $oldest = get_posts([ 'order' => 'ASC'  ] + $args );
        $years  = [
            'from' => $oldest ? mysql2date( 'Y', $oldest[0]->post_date_gmt ) : '',
            'to'   => $newest ? mysql2date( 'Y', $newest[0]->post_date_gmt ) : '',
        ];

        update_option( 'copyright_years', $years );
    }

    return $years;
}

/**
 * Bust the cache.
 */
function wpse_226627_flush_years( $post_id ) {
    if ( in_array( get_post_type( $post_id ), get_post_types([ 'public' => true ]) ) )
        update_option( 'copyright_years', '' );
}

add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'wpse_226627_flush_years' );
add_action( 'save_post',          'wpse_226627_flush_years' );
```

This way the cache is flushed & populated only when a post is created/updated/deleted, so a couple of extra queries (instead of one direct database call) is no real biggy here.

```
$years     = wpse_226627_get_years();
$copyright = $years['from'];
if ( $years['from'] != $years['to'] )
    $copyright .= ' &mdash; ' . $years['to'];
```

I chose to cache the years as a serialized array (as opposed to the compiled copyright string) so that you've always got the values to work with independently, should you ever wish to change their layout/do something differently with them.